# How can i add more than on paralel corpus or monolingual model into my custom model ? - Multiple inheritance

Tags: translation, ibm-watson, watson, language-translation

When I create a new model, how can I add more than one `MonolingualCorpus` or `Parallel Corpus` in Java because the method only accepts one `InputStream` for each model.

```
TranslationModel modelFirst = new CreateModelOptions.Builder()
  .baseModelId("en-fr")
  .name(p.getName())
  .forcedGlossary(new FileInputStream(new File("forced1")))
  .parallelCorpus(new FileInputStream(new File("paralel1")))
  .monolingualCorpus(new FileInputStream(new File("mono1")))
  .build();
```

Because otherwise, I don't understand the utility to create each time a new model if when I want to make a translation, I need to specify the ID of my custom model.

If I create a model with a forcedGlossary and a `ParallelCorpus`, the function returns me a new Model ID, for example, 12345.

After that, I want to add one `ParallelCorpus` and one Monolingual Model to this same model (ModelFirst). So I need to recreate a new model...

```
TranslationModel modelSecond = new CreateModelOptions.Builder()
  .baseModelId(12345)
  .name(p.getName())
  .parallelCorpus(new FileInputStream(new File("paralel2")))
  .monolingualCorpus(new FileInputStream(new File("mono2.txt")))
  .build();
```

Now id of `ModelSecond = 4567`.

- If I translate with the ModelFirst(12345), will Watson use the model from the ModelFirst **AND** from the ModelSecond **or ONLY** from the ModelFirst ??
- If I translate with ModelSecond, Will it inherit my ModelFirst and basic model?
- Can a model have multiple inheritance ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a model with only 1 Monolingual Corpus. If you need to add more than one I would suggest you combine the models into one.

Custom models can only be created out of base models. There is no such thing as an inheritance for custom models.